# How can I alter the view?

Tags: sql-server

How can I alter the view that looks as following:

```
SELECT ...    
FROM     dbo.T_CounterAgent RIGHT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.T_City RIGHT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.T_CounterAgent AS T_CounterAgent_1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.T_Users ON T_CounterAgent_1.ID = dbo.T_Users.CounterAgentID LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.T_Cashdesk INNER JOIN
         dbo.T_ReservAmount ON dbo.T_Cashdesk.ReservAmountID = dbo.T_ReservAmount.ID ON dbo.T_Users.CashdeskID = dbo.T_Cashdesk.ID ON 
         dbo.T_City.ID = dbo.T_Users.CityID ON dbo.T_CounterAgent.ID = dbo.T_Cashdesk.CounterAgentID LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.T_UserRightGroup INNER JOIN
         dbo.T_UserRight ON dbo.T_UserRightGroup.ID = dbo.T_UserRight.GroupID ON dbo.T_Users.UserRightID = dbo.T_UserRight.ID
```

I need to add one more table T_UsersPhones that should be connected to T_Users table by:

T_Users.ID -> T_UsersPhones.UserID

Comment: I'm not sure how to add new join.

Comment: I do not like the fact you do not have `ON` clauses on your `RIGHT` joins. Is that a real case?

Comment: Yes. That's real case.

Comment: I noticed the `ON`s further down the road.... You should try avoiding mixing Rights and Lefts. I usually start of the main table (users seem to be the one in your case) and then add left joins. But this is an advise and not related to your question

Comment: Is it me, or is the above code just not valid? More than one JOINS have no condition, while further on multiple ON's are specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ...    
FROM     dbo.T_CounterAgent RIGHT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.T_City RIGHT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.T_CounterAgent AS T_CounterAgent_1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.T_Users ON T_CounterAgent_1.ID = dbo.T_Users.CounterAgentID LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.T_Cashdesk INNER JOIN
         dbo.T_ReservAmount ON dbo.T_Cashdesk.ReservAmountID = dbo.T_ReservAmount.ID ON dbo.T_Users.CashdeskID = dbo.T_Cashdesk.ID ON 
         dbo.T_City.ID = dbo.T_Users.CityID ON dbo.T_CounterAgent.ID = dbo.T_Cashdesk.CounterAgentID LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.T_UserRightGroup INNER JOIN
         dbo.T_UserRight ON dbo.T_UserRightGroup.ID = dbo.T_UserRight.GroupID ON dbo.T_Users.UserRightID = dbo.T_UserRight.ID LEFT JOIN
         dbo.T_UsersPhones ON dbo.T_Users.ID = dbo.T_UsersPhones.UserID
```

You should really start using alliases as it would help greatly in readability.

Answer (score 0):

From the [top google result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173846.aspx)

```
ALTER VIEW HumanResources.EmployeeHireDate
AS
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, e.HireDate
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS e JOIN Person.Person AS  p
ON e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID
WHERE HireDate < CONVERT(DATETIME,'20020101',101) ;
GO
```

Comment: Yes. The question is how to add new join.